# ordenar de mayor a menor array de objetos extraidos desde firebase con angularfire2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, firebase, ionic2

necesito ordenar este array de objetos

```
  ben: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  e93menor = 9999;
  e93mayor = 0;

  this.ben = this.database.list('/Bencina');
  this.ben.forEach(element =>{
       this.b = [];
       element.forEach(ele =>{
           if(ele.idCiudad == this.idCiudadGlobal){
               //console.log(ele)
             if(ele.idTipoBencina == this.idTipoBencina){
                if(parseInt(ele.precioBencina) >= this.e93mayor){                        
                        this.e93mayor = ele.precioBencina;
  //SEGÚN MI LÓGICA AQUI DEBERIA GUARDARME LOS ELEMENTOS DE MAYOR A MENOR  
                        this.b.push(ele);
                        console.log(ele);
                }    
            }else{
            }

         }
     })
```

})

Answer (score 1):

#### Lo tienes bien montado, sólo tienes que retornarlo en el mapeo.

```
this.ben = this.database.list('/Bencina')
  .map(arr => arr.filter(el => {
    el.idCiudad == this.idCiudadGlobal &&
    el.idTipoBencina == this.idTipoBencina &&
    parseInt(el.precioBencina) >= this.e93mayor
  }).map(el => {
    // ¿Estás seguro sobreescribir el valor? 
    this.e93mayor = el.precioBencina;
    return el;
  })
});
```

Comment: no entiendo muy bien tu código

Comment: Te explico: Primero mapeamos los datos, esto lo que hace es devolver un nuevo array, con los datos que retorne dentro del map. Dentro del mapeo lo que hago es filtrar tu listado de elementos con las condiciones que mencionamos, el filtrado siempre debe de retornar un booleano, el ya te dará el objeto si cumple, en este caso un array de objetos y por ultimo mapeo el resultado del filtrado para aplicar lo que buscabas, asignar el precioBencina a tu variable e93mayor.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo una pequeña función que hice para poder ordenar un array.

```js
/**
 * Famosa función para acomodar crono o alfabéticamente un array
 * @param data El array con los datos
 * @param key El campo para ordenar
 * @param orden El sentido del orden
 * @example sortJSON(miarray, 'fecha', 'asc')
 * @copyright 2016, Fernando Magrosoto V.
 */
function sortJSON(data, key, orden) {
  return data.sort(function (a, b) {
    var x = a[key],
      y = b[key];

    if (orden === 'asc') {
      return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    }

    if (orden === 'desc') {
      return ((x > y) ? -1 : ((x < y) ? 1 : 0));
    }
  });
}
```

Desde Firebase, almacenas en un array el resultado del snap.val() y lo ordenas.
Espero te sirva.